# How to commit all the Android Studio Projects on my PC to a private GitHub repository?

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I am trying to commit all my Android Studio projects in a private repository.

Is there any way to move all of them in a single directory and commit them in a single repository?

Note: Knowing how can I get them in a single directory would be more than enough. I gave the other background details, just in case if there was some direct way (to avoid that XY problem).

Comment: Android Studio projects usually don't require to be located in a certain directory. You can freely move them around - just move the project directory (while Android Studio is closed of course).

Comment: Maybe a place where I could find a list of all the recent projects so I could manually do it

Comment: For some reason, I cannot get all the opened projects ... maybe because I recently upgraded to a new version

Comment: I read multiple questions here: 1. How do I create a Git repository on my computer? 2. How do I find all of my Android Studio projects? 3. How do I add those projects to the Git repository? 4. How do I create a GitHub repository? 5. How do I upload my local repository to the new GitHub repository? I suggest solving each of these separately. Breaking down a problem into smaller parts like this always makes it more manageable. Which of these do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

By default, recent versions of Android Studio create your projects as a subfolder of `C:\Users\<your user name>\StudioProjects`. I would start by looking there.